# variable are perforoming task? but error displayed

Tags: php

in prgram task have performed but .....?

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 293

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 293

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 304

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 304

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 322

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 322

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 331

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php on line 331

result is displayed in in image
image is given bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bKFp.png)

**

### these are code

**

```html
<pre>

   
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>petrol amount</th> <th>deasel amount </th><th>total</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "_"      ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $petrol_sl_amount    . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $desel_sl_amount . "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$p_d =$desel_sl_amount+$petrol_sl_amount ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>wisooli</th> <th>petrol+deasel amount </th><th>total</th></tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "_"    ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $wisoli_total    . "</td>";
echo "<td>" .  $p_d  . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $t_p_d=$p_d+$wisoli_total ."</td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>credit/khanat</th></tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . ""    . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $cridit_amt      ."</td>";

echo "</tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>per day expansis</th></tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "_"   ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $expan_amount   ."</td>";
echo "<td>" .  $ex_cr= $cridit_amt + $expan_amount ."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>remaining amount</th></tr>";


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .     "_"  ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $final=$t_p_d-$ex_cr . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
</pre>
```

*

```html
<h1>along with result notice error are diplayed</h1>
<th>sr#</th> <th>petrol amount</th> <th>deasel amount </th><th>total</th></tr><tr><td>_</td><td>8246.7</td></td><td>8246.7</td></td><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>293</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>293</b><br />
<td>16493.4</td></tr><tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>wisooli</th> <th>petrol+deasel amount </th><th>total</th></tr><tr><td>_</td><td>592153</td></td><td>16493.4</td></td><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>304</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>304</b><br />
<td>608646.4</td></tr><tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>credit/khanat</th></tr><tr><td></td><td>35802</td></td></tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>per day expansis</th></tr><tr><td>_</td><td>4200</td></td><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>322</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>322</b><br />
<td>40002</td></tr><tr>
<th>sr#</th> <th>remaining amount</th></tr><tr><td>_</td><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>331</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\al_murtaza_home\selector.php</b> on line <b>331</b><br />
<td>568644.4</td></tr>
```

*

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you do not post your code?

Comment: And your php code in line 293, 304, 322, 331 is...? Second: set error reporting as needed, either in php.ini or with function call: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Most likely the variables you try to add in expressions like `$desel_sl_amount+$petrol_sl_amount` do not hold numeric values. Maybe they are empty, maybe `null`, maybe they hold some string. We cannot say, you will have to check yourself.

Comment: cod have added result is shown in image!

Comment: these ar not null task is perform but along with task result warning error are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you need cast few variables to int to avoid this notice

```
<?php 
      $petrol_sl_amount = $desel_sl_amount = $wisoli_total = $cridit_amt = $expan_amount = 12 ;

      echo "<table>
      <tr>
      <th>sr#</th> <th>petrol amount</th> <th>deasel amount </th><th>total</th> 
      </tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . "_"      ."</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $petrol_sl_amount    . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $desel_sl_amount . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" .$p_d =$desel_sl_amount+$petrol_sl_amount ."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       echo "<tr>
       <th>sr#</th> <th>wisooli</th> <th>petrol+deasel amount </th><th>total</th> 
   </tr>";


    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . "_"    ."</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $wisoli_total    . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .  $p_d  . "</td>";

     echo "<td>" . $t_p_d=(int)$p_d+$wisoli_total ."</td>";

   echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr> <th>sr#</th> <th>credit/khanat</th></tr>";


    echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . ""    . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $cridit_amt      ."</td>";

   echo "</tr> <th>sr#</th> <th>per day expansis</th></tr>";


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "_"   ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $expan_amount   ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .  $ex_cr= (int)$cridit_amt + $expan_amount ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr><th>sr#</th> <th>remaining amount</th></tr>";


   echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" .     "_"  ."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $final=(int)$t_p_d-(int)$ex_cr . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   ?>
```